# Consider using a DataContractResolver serialization error

Tags: c#, serialization, asp.net-web-api

My desktop wpf application communicates with mvc 4 web api. I'm trying to read all database entries. This is simple interface:

```
public interface IEventRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Event> GetAll();
}
```

And this is the repository:

```
public class EventRepository : IEventRepository
{
    private List<Event> events = new List<Event>();
    public EventRepository()
    {
        HeronEntities context = new HeronEntities();
        events = context.Events.ToList();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Event> GetAll()
    {
        return events;
    }
 }
```

This is the controller:

```
 public class EventController : ApiController
{
    static readonly IEventRepository repository = new EventRepository();

    public IEnumerable<Event> GetAllEvents()
    {
        return repository.GetAll();
    }
}
```

Event class looks like this:

```
public partial class Event
{
    public Event()
    {
        this.Comments = new HashSet<Comment>();
        this.Rates = new HashSet<Rate>();
        this.RawDates = new HashSet<RawDate>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public string SiteURL { get; set; }
    public string ContactEmail { get; set; }
    public string LogoURL { get; set; }
    public int EventType_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Location_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> BegginingDate { get; set; }
    public string nTrain { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public virtual Conference Conference { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Rate> Rates { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RawDate> RawDates { get; set; }
    public virtual EventType EventType { get; set; }
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to access the controller, I get above mentioned `failed to serialize the response body for content type` of error. There is some problem with `Event` class serialization. I used the exact same code with classes containing primitive types and it worked perfectly. What's the best way to overcome this kind of serialization problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have disabled lazy loading and proxy class generation. That solved the problem.

```
public EventRepository()
    {
        HeronEntities context = new HeronEntities();
        context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        events = context.Events.ToList();
    }
```